# Java - UserInput.* doesn't work on my Mac

Tags: java, macos, user-input

I do most of programming work on the Windows terminals in my university. However, my computer is a Mac and, for some reason, the javac command throws up an error when I use UserInput methods. Is there anything to install or an alternative command to use to make this compile properly?

Comment: I believe the error message would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using at university a special package UserInput given by your teacher or something like that. If it's the case, then you just need to "install" that package on your mac, or use the java.util.Scanner class to deal with user input.

Answer (score 1):

Which UserInput methods? There's no UserInput class in JDK 6. Which package were you expecting them to be in?